# show "Could not find 'xcodeproj'" during pop install podfile

Tags: cocoapods, kubernetes-pod

during install popfile will show error message like following message.

[image]

```
Generating Pods project
[!] An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.

undefined local variable or method `installer' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fee7794a0f8>
Did you mean?  install!

/Users/peggytsai/Documents/wavegis/Water_ios 下午4.12.08/Podfile:45:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:179:in `post_install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:647:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:635:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:634:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:186:in `block in generate_pods_project'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in `generate_pods_project'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

how do i install cocoapods popfile?

[Update] cocoapods version is 1.5.3

[Update]  cocoapods

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tag [tag:pod] has description `DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Instead, prefer a specific tag like [kubernetes-pod] or [cocoapods]` So probably you should change it to something relevant.

Comment: Please copy/paste logs, not screenshot.

Comment: @Larme OK! i update it!

Comment: Show your podfile too. Also, that's the whole error message? Because in your screenshots it seemed to be more.

Comment: @Larme update it

Comment: I don't think you're showing the right Podfile. The one you posted doesn't have a line 45 referenced in the error message from  /Users/peggytsai/Documents/wavegis/Water_ios 下午4.12.08/Podfile

Comment: @PaulBeusterien it is correct podfile, i update the podfile.

Comment: There is a typo in your Podfile. Use `installer_representation` rather than `installer`